# Easy way to get array of selected indexes of CheckBoxList in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkboxlist

Is there a property or a method on the CheckBoxList class that will return an array of ints that represents all of the selected indexes?  This is in ASP.NET.

Comment: According to the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkboxlist(v=vs.110).aspx), there doesn't appear to be. You'll have to iterate the items yourself.

Comment: Yeah, @j.f. I don't know why that isn't built in. Thanks, though.

Comment: Hey, @j.f., would you mind voting up my question so I can earn my Student badge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkboxlist(v=vs.110).aspx), there doesn't appear to be. You'll have to iterate the items yourself.

Here is a method that does just that. It iterates each item, checks if it is selected, then adds the index to a list. I use a list because a list is mutable whereas an array is not. Then to return an array, I just call `ToArray()` on the list.

```
public int[] selectedIndexesOfCheckBoxList(CheckBoxList chkList)
{
    List<int> selectedIndexes = new List<int>();

    foreach (ListItem item in chkList.Items)
    {
        if (item.Selected)
        {
            selectedIndexes.Add(chkList.Items.IndexOf(item));
        }
    }

    return selectedIndexes.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Hey, j.f., would you mind up-voting my question so I can earn my Student badge?

Answer (score 1):

You could create an extension method to simulate the behavior you want.  The benefit of that being that you could re-use it on any list control.  Below is a rough example (I'm just returning the list of strings of the values, you could return anything though, the index, the value, the entire list item, etc.).

```
public static List<string> SelectedValues(this ListControl lst)
{
    List<string> returnLst = new List<string>();

    foreach (ListItem li in lst.Items)
    {
        if (li.Selected == true)
        {
            returnLst.Add(li.Value);
        }

    return returnLst;
}
```

Comment: That's not how you define an [extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) in C#, BTW.

Comment: You're right @DStanley, I updated the example.  This would need to be in a static class also.